# Hello world with German umlauts and other unusual characters ä ö ü ß @ ￼ ♫ Ꞧ € ᴀ ꟽ ㍻

Tags: eclipse, console

Unicode chars in the eclipse console are not the same as in the class file. But all other views show the right chars. is that a bug in the eclipse console? (System.out) Look at the Screenshot, Thanks
[image]

Comment: It probably just means the font being used by the console doesn't contain the characters displayed as ?

Comment: thank you, can i change that?

Comment: In the Preferences go to 'General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts' look for 'Console font' in the 'Debug' section.

Comment: i check that ... i change with "edit default" and all views change the font but the ? chars in the console is still here

Answer (score 0):

You probably got an inappropriate console encoding in your launch configuration. You can change it in Run -> Run Configurations... in the Common tab (see screenshot). The default encoding comes either from the project properties or the workbench setting at Preferences -> General -> Workspace.

[image]